# How to find out if the yuv420 video has full or limited color range?

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

I'm searching for a reliable way to distinguish between the

- *full-range (PC)* and
- *limited range (TV)*

pixel formats in a given video.

(Particularly, I will be satisfied with a solution for Y'UV 4:2:0 H.264 videos in the MP4 container.)

So my question is

**How to reliably determine whether a particular video is full-ranged or limited ranged?**

---

Here is what I did to find a reliable way:
I created 3 testing videos with commands

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc2=d=1                             test1.mp4
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc2=d=1 -vf scale=out_range=full    test2.mp4  
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc2=d=1 -vf scale=out_range=limited test3.mp4
```

which is the same as

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc2=d=1                             test1.mp4
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc2=d=1 -vf scale=out_range=pc      test2.mp4  
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc2=d=1 -vf scale=out_range=tv      test3.mp4
```

They created these files:

> ```
> test1.mp4  36,974 bytes
> test2.mp4  40,178 bytes
> test3.mp4  36,974 bytes
> ```

where `test1.mp4` and `test3.mp4` have not only the same size, but they are *binary identical*, too.

While processing these commands, FFmpeg shows this message in the appropriate line of `Output #0` section (I show the message lines of these individual `ffmpeg` commands together, respectively, to see differences):

> ```
> Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive),     ... 
> Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(pc, progressive), ...
> Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, progressive), ...
> ```

Using `ffprobe` after creating videos, the appropriate lines (now from the `Input #0` section) will be

> ```
> Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive),      ...
> Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, progressive), ...
> Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive),      ...
> ```

Note changes in lines 2 and 3:

- pixel format for full range *changes* from `yuv420p` to `yuvj420p` (which is strange, because developers of FFmpeg themselves discourage using this pixel format as an *obsolete* one),
- limited range is *not more mentioned* (no “tv” in parentheses).

Now I will omit the `test1.mp4`, because it is the same as `test3.mp4`.

So I have 2 videos, `test2.mp4` with full-range and `test3.mp4` with limited range. The difference is visible (no such bright colors), as in these 2 screenshots placed one just below the other:

[image]

The difference in the `ffprobe` output is in the pixel format, as I already demonstrated: `yuvj420p` vs. `yuv420p`.

But the `yuvj420p` is an obsolete pixel format, so if I want to tell if the video is full range, I probably can't rely on its occurrence in the `ffprobe` output as an indicator of the full-range video.

---

I thank that a reliable way to distinguish between full-range and limited range is to *find values outside of limited range,* i.e.,

- outside of interval [16, 235] for the luma component (Y'), or
- outside of interval [16, 240] for color components (U, V).

So I used the *signalstats* filter as in this command

```
ffprobe -f lavfi movie='test3.mp4',signalstats \
        -show_entries frame_tags=lavfi.signalstats.YMIN,lavfi.signalstats.YMAX
```

and filtered the output to see only outliers.

The `test2.mp4` video (full-ranged) gives me many of them:

> ```
> TAG:lavfi.signalstats.YMIN=3
> TAG:lavfi.signalstats.YMIN=6
> TAG:lavfi.signalstats.YMIN=9
> TAG:lavfi.signalstats.YMAX=237
> TAG:lavfi.signalstats.YMIN=10
> TAG:lavfi.signalstats.YMIN=10
> TAG:lavfi.signalstats.YMIN=6
> TAG:lavfi.signalstats.YMAX=240
> TAG:lavfi.signalstats.YMIN=7
> TAG:lavfi.signalstats.YMIN=0
> TAG:lavfi.signalstats.YMIN=7
> TAG:lavfi.signalstats.YMAX=237
> TAG:lavfi.signalstats.YMIN=1
> TAG:lavfi.signalstats.YMIN=7
> TAG:lavfi.signalstats.YMIN=7
> TAG:lavfi.signalstats.YMIN=7
> TAG:lavfi.signalstats.YMIN=7
> TAG:lavfi.signalstats.YMIN=7
> TAG:lavfi.signalstats.YMIN=5
> TAG:lavfi.signalstats.YMIN=7
> TAG:lavfi.signalstats.YMIN=7
> TAG:lavfi.signalstats.YMIN=1
> TAG:lavfi.signalstats.YMIN=4
> TAG:lavfi.signalstats.YMIN=7
> TAG:lavfi.signalstats.YMAX=239
> TAG:lavfi.signalstats.YMIN=7
> TAG:lavfi.signalstats.YMAX=239
> TAG:lavfi.signalstats.YMIN=7
> TAG:lavfi.signalstats.YMAX=239
> TAG:lavfi.signalstats.YMIN=4
> TAG:lavfi.signalstats.YMIN=7
> TAG:lavfi.signalstats.YMAX=239
> ```

But for my surprise, the `test3.mp4` video with *limited* range **gives me outliers, too**:

> ```
> TAG:lavfi.signalstats.YMIN=11
> TAG:lavfi.signalstats.YMIN=11
> ```

So it is NOT a reliable way.

Let me repeat my question, accompanied by 2 secondary ones:

Main question:

- **How to reliably distinguish full-ranged and limited ranged videos?**

Two tangential questions:

- Why a video, created *fully* with FFmpeg, has an *obsolete pixel format* `yuvj420p`, discouraged by FFmpeg developers?
- Why in a *limited-range* video are still values *outside permitted range*?

Answer (score -1):

1. yuvj420p is not obsolete, the ffmpeg message is just misleading
2. Compression errors? It doesn't really matter - all values less than 16 will be 16. Same with values over 235.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).